# Convert m2ts to (if possible) lossless format for m2ts to save space?

Tags: video, video-conversion

I have hundreds of m2ts formatted video files resulting from legal recordings from TV. Now I would like to keep them, but they are huge.

Is there a format I can convert them to  which is preferably loss-less? MKV container would be nice, but not necessary, as is readability by iPad.

Linux or Mac solutions are fine.

---

Edits and Additional Info:

Edit 1:

```
01:20:56 {master} ~/Documents/Projects/ASM_Optimization$ mediainfo /Volumes/Disque\ dur/Enregistrements/Arte\ -\ A\ la\ decouverte\ de\ la\ Patagonie\ -\ 19-12-2015\ 20h45\ 04h10\ \(1303\).m2ts
General
ID                                       : 47931 (0xBB3B)
Complete name                            : /Volumes/Disque dur/Enregistrements/Arte - A la decouverte de la Patagonie - 19-12-2015 20h45 04h10 (1303).m2ts
Format                                   : BDAV
Format/Info                              : Blu-ray Video
File size                                : 8.01 GiB
Duration                                 : 4h 9mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 4 587 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 720 (0x2D0)
Menu ID                                  : 47931 (0xBB3B)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 4h 9mn
Width                                    : 1 440 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : MBAFF
Scan type, store method                  : Interleaved fields
Scan order                               : Top Field First

Audio #1
ID                                       : 730 (0x2DA)
Menu ID                                  : 47931 (0xBB3B)
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : HE-AAC / LC
Muxing mode                              : ADTS
Codec ID                                 : 15
Duration                                 : 4h 9mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz / 24.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 23.438 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -84ms
Language                                 : French

Audio #2
ID                                       : 731 (0x2DB)
Menu ID                                  : 47931 (0xBB3B)
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : HE-AAC / LC
Muxing mode                              : ADTS
Codec ID                                 : 15
Duration                                 : 4h 9mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz / 24.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 23.438 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -172ms
Language                                 : qaa

Audio #3
ID                                       : 732 (0x2DC)
Menu ID                                  : 47931 (0xBB3B)
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : HE-AAC / LC
Muxing mode                              : ADTS
Codec ID                                 : 15
Duration                                 : 4h 9mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz / 24.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 23.438 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -318ms
Language                                 : German

Audio #4
ID                                       : 733 (0x2DD)
Menu ID                                  : 47931 (0xBB3B)
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : HE-AAC / LC
Muxing mode                              : ADTS
Codec ID                                 : 15
Duration                                 : 4h 9mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz / 24.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 23.438 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -206ms
Language                                 : qad

Text #1
ID                                       : 70 (0x46)-888
Menu ID                                  : 47931 (0xBB3B)
Format                                   : Teletext Subtitle
Language                                 : French
Language, more info                      : For hearing impaired people

Text #2
ID                                       : 70 (0x46)-889
Menu ID                                  : 47931 (0xBB3B)
Format                                   : Teletext Subtitle
Language                                 : French
```

Comment: Lossless video at any reasonable resolution *is* big. You will have to trade *something* here. Let's say this is 576 lines (interlaced) at 3:4 aspect ratio (768 pixels wide by 576 pixels high) at 25 frames per second. That gives 576 * 768 * 25 = 11 Mpx/s that we need to store. At lossless, you might hope for 50% compression ratio at best, depending on image content, and assume 24 bpp. That's about 16 MB/s or 56 GB/hour before considering audio, and assuming that 50% compression ratio.

Comment: OK - I see your point. I don't know that much about video formats - I added the ```mediainfo``` of one of the files - can I compress it lossless? even 50% would be fine with me.

Comment: Not really. Your source is anamorphic Full HD AVC. Re-encoding with x264 CRF 23, you may get ~20-30% savings before quality visibly degrades.

Comment: I never converted video as this whole container - codec issue is something I am not to comfortable with. So: how could I convert the video to x264 CRF 23? HandBrake I guess - but where can I foind the CRF23 option?

Comment: Found it - the Constant Quality slider.

Answer (score 1):

From [this site re iPad playback](http://www.apple.com/ipad-air-2/specs/):

> Video formats supported: H.264 video up to 1080p, 60 frames per
>   second, High Profile level 5.0 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps,
>   48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; MPEG-4 video
>   up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Proﬁle
>   with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in
>   .m4v, .mp4, and .mov ﬁle formats; Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps,
>   1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo
>   audio in .avi ﬁle format

There are no lossless codecs supported by iPad - if you wish to play these back the most viable option is H.264/MPEG-4.

Lossless formats are by definition going to be huge file sizes (A comment above from @MichaelKjörling above demonstrates this). You will need to decide how you'd prefer to take a hit in file size, such as in resolution, bit rate or compression format, and bear in mind if the compression is too high you will need a good machine to decompress it quick enough for smooth playback.

Comment: Handbreak would be one easy to use tool for converting MPEG-2 to H.264 MPEG-4 files. With minimal visual quality loss, the final files will be 50-100% smaller than original MPEG-2 files.

Comment: @Jono This sounds like a good option. Is there a Built-in preset in Handbrake I could use? Or would be ffmpeg (which options) better?